# Angular 4 : radio button : set selected (with 2 way data binding)

Tags: angular

I would like to set the selected radio button based on some input during the ngOninit. I would like to use 2-way data binding.

How to solve this? This (and similar tries) don't work:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-xs-3"><label>Checker</label></div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="checker" name="checker" value="0" [checked]="checker==0">Nee</label>
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="checker" name="checker" value="1" [checked]="checker==1">Akkoord</label>
      <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="checker" name="checker" value="2" [checked]="checker==2">Geen</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: These `[checked]="checker==0"` are useless. And the values of the radio buttons are strings, not numbers. http://plnkr.co/edit/TQJz0GD4tVEGfOajhjJw?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet - thank you! Can you put this text also in an Answer? Then I will mark it is solved with +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value property contains a string (value="0" is equivalent to [value]="'0'") and it looks like checker variable contains a number and if we look at the writeValue method in RadioControlValueAccessor, we find that Angular use the strict comparison with the === operator.

So, to fix the problem we must add the brackets like this: [value]="0". In this case the value property will contains a number and the test checker === value will be true if the two variables contains the same value.

Also, checked binding should be removed.